# Convert an XLTX File to PDF via VBA in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to basically do a Save As on an Excel file on our shared drive to a PDF format within our Access database using VBA.  Currently the user has to go to File -> 'Save as Adobe PDF' hundreds of times a day for every excel file it produces.

The data is first exported from Access to an Excel template which is how the excel file gets generated.  Its from here, after the Excel is made, where I'd like to do the 'save as'.

Comment: Show the code you have to create the Excel files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use in my project:

```
Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
With oExcel
    .Workbooks.Open "C:\MyExcel.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=0
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Visible = False   
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
End With
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:="C:\MyPDFFile.pdf"
```

ExportAsFixedFormat is built in Access function.